# Return code for beeline command in shell script

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

How to capture the return code of the Beeline command that I am executing within a Shell Script. Like Below:

beeline -u $Beeline -e "ALTER TABLE  DROP if exists partition (date='');"

I want to capture the status of above query with in shell script.

Thanks
AG

Answer (score 0):

`$?` captures the return code of the previous statement. Store the result in a variable or use `$?` for more processing later.

```
beeline -u $Beeline -e "ALTER TABLE DROP if exists partition (date='');"
rc=$?
#do whatever with $rc here
```